# asp.net radiobutton list action in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewContactOptions" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
         Width="494px">
        <Columns>
           
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VERIFICATION">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList AutoPostBack="true" ID="RBL1" runat="server" Enabled="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">APPROVERD</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">NOT APPROVED</asp:ListItem>                       
                                          
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I had inserted a radiobutton list in gridview . IF USER SELECTS ANY OF THE OPTION FROM RADIOBUTTON LIST THEN IT SHOULD BE REFLECTED IN DATABASE.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried or search for Grideview.Rows.FindControl(). I assume that you need it.

Comment: m unable to retrieve the index of selected row.

Comment: Mr Sahu my code is as above.